# Axios Config with Auth Header, best practise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am setting up JWT authentication, everything is working fine but I got stuck at the last piece where I am not sure what I should do.

I have set up my Axios Config as this:

```
const token = ""

export const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      },
});
```

so here are few problems I have ..

1. if I want to log in, I need to have the "Auth" field to be gone, since I am not sending any cookie, if I do so, my backend fires an Exception since the cookie is not complete
2. How should I go about the Axios config, should I fill the "token" variable OR should I work here with the cookie in the local storage?
3. Is it a good practice to have multiple configs and use them simultaneously depending on the situation?

hope anyone can help me out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming accross this question, to handle such situations i use `axios.interceptors` which let you access a certain event inbetween the request and response, that way you can handle the **Auth Token** and also in case of the "need" to refresh the token, it also should be handled here.

Multiple Axios Configs are also a way to go, but not necessary for that case,
pointing out [here.](https://thedutchlab.com/blog/using-axios-interceptors-for-refreshing-your-api-token)

Comment: You can create multiple instances of axios also. 1 instance with the auth header and one without.

```javascript
    const unauthorized = axios.create()
    const authorized = axios.create({ headers: {'Authorized': 'Bearer mytoken'})
```
Then you can keep reusing each instance as situaltion is needed. This way the code will document itself with variable name also.